# how to make persistent JMS messages with java spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jms, activemq-classic

I am trying to make a queue with activemq and spring boot using this [link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/) and it looks fine. What I am unable to do is to make this queue persistent after application goes down. I think that `SimpleJmsListenerContainerFactory` should be durable to achieve that but when I set `factory.setSubscriptionDurable(true)` and `factory.setClientId("someid")` I am unable to receive messages any more. I would be greatfull for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are embedding the broker in your application. While this is ok for integration tests and proof of concepts, you should consider having a broker somewhere in your infrastructure and connect to it. If you choose that, refer to the ActiveMQ documentation and you should be fine.

If you insist on embedding it, you need to provide [a `brokerUrl` that enables message persistence](http://activemq.apache.org/broker-uri.html).

Having said that, it looks like you misunderstand durable subscriber and message persistence. The latter can be achieved by having a broker that actually stores the content of the queue somewhere so that if the broker is stopped and restarted, it can restore the content of its queue. The former is to be able to receive a message even if the listener is not active at a period of time.

Comment: hmm well when I try to create and register broker manually it says that it is already registered because I think spring boot did it when it found activeMQ on the classpath. I have no idea how to configure it. All information or examples that I read are only for XML configuration but I want to do this by annotations.

Comment: Have you looked [at the configuration at least](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-activemq)?! You can just set a property with the brokerUrl and we'll do the rest (see the `brokerUrl` link in my answer). The property is `spring.activemq.broker-url`

Comment: well yes I didn't understand how that broker worked now it's fine with external broker but still I have some issues with broker that spring boot provides but about that I will write another topic

Answer (score 0):

you can enable persistence of messages using ActiveMQConnectionFactory.

as mentioned in the spring boot link you provided, this ActiveMQConnectionFactory gets created automatically by spring boot.so you can have this bean in your application configuration created manually and you can set various property as well.

```
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory cf = new   ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost?broker.persistent=true");
```

Here is the link http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-embed-a-broker-inside-a-connection.html